# OpenSSH ignores "AllowTcpForwarding no" in sshd_config

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ubuntu-16.04

On ubuntu 16.04.3 / OpenSSH_7.2p2 disabling Tunneling globally
by setting these values in /etc/ssh/sshd_config has no effect and Dynamic / Local tunnels still work

```
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
AllowStreamLocalForwarding no
PermitOpen none
PermitTunnel no
X11Forwarding no
```

Update:
I can only make it work by using "Match" on selected User(s)

```
Match User zuser
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  AllowStreamLocalForwarding no
  PermitOpen none
  PermitTunnel no
```

Comment: Did you restart sshd?

Comment: Yes, I even rebooted to make sure

Comment: I just tested on a VM with ubuntu 16.04.3 / OpenSSH_7.2p2 and it's the same behavior can anyone test on ubuntu server 16.04 with latest updates I'm starting to believe it's a bug

Answer (score 5):

*OpenSSH* will unexpectedly apply settings when using `Match` and not apply settings when not using `Match` if at some earlier position in the configuration there is another `Match block`.

The following example demonstrates this:

```
Match Group sudo
  # this is applied to sudo members
  ClientAliveInterval 20
  # this is applied to sudo members
  AllowTcpForwarding yes

# one might assume that the Match block has ended here - it did not
# the following is ALSO applied to sudo members only
X11Forwarding
AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Though most configuration is using indentation for better readability, a `Match` does not end when indentation ends.

> If all of the criteria on the Match line are satisfied, the keywords
>   on the following lines override those set in the global section of the
>   config file, **until either another Match line or the end of the
>   file**

OpenSSH will only notice unintended configuration changes from inappropriate `Match` insertion if one of those options is not valid in that context. Otherwise, following instructions are simply becoming dependent on that `Match` condition.

**The unexpected configuration can be resolved by inserting all `Match` blocks strictly at the very end of the configuration file - and placing all unconditional configuration strictly above the first `Match` line.**

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work fine for me in a Vagrant box (openssh-server 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.2)

```
AllowTcpForwarding no
```

/var/log/auth.log:

```
Nov 22 16:19:41 packer-qemu sshd[1164]: refused local port forward: originator 127.0.0.1 port 44540, target localhost port 22 Nov 22 16:19:46 packer-qemu sshd[1164]: refused local port forward: originator 127.0.0.1 port 44546, target localhost port 22
```

Are you sure you don't have something else in your configuration file which overrides your setting somehow? (Like a match statement)

Comment: dont you mean "AllowTcpForwarding yes"?

Comment: No, OP asked a question about "AllowTcpForwarding no", so that's what I tried to reproduce. The log shows that the setting works as expected.